# Sprite Kit equivalent of clipsToBounds:

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I would like to add moving child nodes on a Sprite node, but want them to be clipped if they move outside the bounds, hence giving an impression of a 'window'. I know there is a `UIView` property called `clipsToBounds` that does the same. Is there a similar property for `SKSpriteNode`, and if not, how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add the sprite supposed to be clipped to a [SKCropNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCropNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html). Then set the crop node's `maskNode` to a sprite node using an image that defines the crop region.